# Why is this plant slanting towards one side?

Tags: sunlight

[image: Golden Duranta Plant]

I had planted this golden duranta from seed about one month ago, presently it's growing but is slanting/tilted towards one side as you can see. When I took this pic in the afternoon, it was still somewhat tall but during cloudy days or in the evening it slants again (you can see that I've placed an old match stick for support against the slanting and the part near the root shows how much the lower part has already slanted).

I'm wondering why is this happening. From what I've read, this only happens when the plant doesn't get enough sunlight. That isn't the case here because my balcony easily gets 4-5 hours of direct sunlight during the day. The only caveat is that my balcony is west facing, so it only gets the "direct" light during the second half of the day (after 1-2 PM). Until that time, the rising sun is on the other side of the building and isn't directly visible from my balcony.

Could this be the reason? One more thing I can add is that the slanting direction is also toward the west. Is it the case that the plant isn't getting enough sunlight?

Comment: It's a bushy-spready-outy kind of plant, right? Not a stands-straight-and-tall sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple [phototropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototropism) - plants grow towards the light (or plant cells lengthen more on the side away from the light, if you want to get picky about it.)

Either turn the plant pot regularly or accept it as normal for a plant that is only strongly lit from one side.